# Track Screenviews

Tags: firebase, flutter, analytics

i was was wondering if i could track the navigation of any app user, and after some research i knew about Track screen using firebase analytics, the documents in this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews mention that i can do this both manually or automatically. However, I am not sure I understood how to apply this in my flutter app. 
Supposedly this is a screen, what should i do in this code to track navigation when the user be navigating in this screen?

```
class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {



  final FirebaseAnalytics analytics;
  final FirebaseAnalyticsObserver observer;
  SecondScreen({this.analytics, this.observer});



  @override
  SecondScreenState createState() => new SecondScreenState();
}

class SecondScreenState extends State<FirstScreen> {

  final FirebaseAnalytics analytics;
  final FirebaseAnalyticsObserver observer;
  SecondScreenState({this.analytics, this.observer});  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Screen"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text('Go back!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any help?

Thanks in advance